# How to center a TextView which has two ImageViews to the left of it?

Tags: android-layout

My requirement is to display a TextView in the center and to the right of two ImageViews which are side by side. Also, if the text is too long it should ellipsize. Could you please let me know if there is any way in which this can be achieved?

Thank you.

Comment: not clear `imageview` then `textview` then `imageview` u want something like this

Comment: No, it should be ImageView ImageView TextView and the TextView should be in the center of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. if it is your requirement

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:text="Testing testing testing testing" />

</RelativeLayout>
```